# PSQL \copy sees extra data, won't import, generate non-serial id

Tags: docker, csv, import, psql

I'm getting this message:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY words, line 1: ",a"
```

This in when I run this command:  `\copy words (word)  FROM '/data/words4.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV);`

The file being imported looks like this:

```
,a
,aah
,aahed
,aahing
,aahs
,aardvark
,aardvarks
,aardwolf
,ab
```

and so on. This is a .csv export from a spreadsheet, opened in VS Code and saved after making a few minor changes. I've tried many variants on the format of the csv: with commas, commas at the end of the line with a return after, etc. etc. and I suppose this is the problem.But it also seems to be something to do with psql not creating the id in the first column; the schema is as follows:

```
              Table "public.words"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | uuid |           | not null | 
 word   | text |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "words_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "uq:words.word" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (word)
```

EDIT: I'm wondering if this has to do with the id being non-null but not serial. This db is used by Vapor, and it normally generates ids as UUIDs. But in this case, it appears that psql can't generate these, and also can't leave the field empty.

Is there a way to cause sql to generate a UUID for the id column? This seems like it should be basic, but I can't find any reference to this particular problem.

In case this affects anything, this is all happening in docker.

Comment: 1) This `,a` is two columns the first column value being `NULL`. If you want to copy only into `word` then do `a`. 2) Yes Postgres can automatically generate a `UUID`. Just use `UUID` function as the `DEFAULT` for the `id` column. For Postgres 13+ you can use a [UUID function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html) for 12- you will need to use the [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) extension to get a function.

Comment: how does this work in the context of a csv import? Also, I did indeed try importing with just a, but that did fail, I think because no value was generated for  the id column.

Comment: If you change `id     | uuid |           | not null |  ` to `id     | uuid |           | not null | gen_random_uuid ()` then `id` will have a `UUID` generated for each record per [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html): *DEFAULT default_expr ... he default expression will be used in any insert operation that does not specify a value for the column.* and [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html): *Table columns not specified in the COPY FROM column list will receive their default values.*.

Comment: that works if you're creating tables in Postgres, but this is part of a vapor app that uses the Fluent ORM, and the default id behaviour doesn't seem to be documented to cover this being added explicitly.... I'm not a db guy, so I probably have missed something...

Comment: See [Models](https://docs.vapor.codes/fluent/model/) for how to override:  *Custom Identifier ... The above example uses an @ID with custom key "foo" and identifier type Int. This is compatible with SQL databases using auto-incrementing primary keys, ...  generatedBy parameter .database  Database is expected to generate a value upon save.*

Answer (score 0):

Solution is more of a work around. The problem does arise from sql not (at least from what I've learned) having facility to generate uuid's. So I regenerated the csv file with a second column, preceding the first, and used a general concatenation formula to generate uuid-patterned strings in the spreadsheet, although I might have been bettor off to do it programmatically.

Either way, exporting that file and copying it in worked.

Comment: See my comment to your question, Postgres can indeed generate UUID's. So a work around is not needed.